# How to plot convolution in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, plot, convolution

So I have a unit step function U(t)-U(t-1) and another function e^(-4t) *U(t). These functions are defined as vectors and vary from t_start to t_end. Now when I take the convolution of this function the resultant vector is almost twice the length of the time vector and hence I cannot use plot function to plot the convolved waveform. Any idea how to match the time axis and the convolution result so they can be plotted ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'same' argument to the [`conv` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) to get the same length out as you put in. Just make sure you give the arguments in the correct order.